# Stuck Kvass fermentation?

Tags: fermentation, carbonation, airlock, alcohol-content

So I was making kvass, and have decided to make it a little more alcoholic. I made it using the following recipe:

Slightly burn 3 pieces of toast, add to boiled water, and 1.5 handfulls of raisins.

Wait 8 hours

add active dry yeast, .5 cups regular sugar, .5 cups brown sugar. Mix everything. Put in new bottle and use baloon as airlock. It has been in airlock since yesterday.

I'm kind of surprised that the baloon isn't filled up a little more. Also, how long should I keep it in this stage? How and how long should I bottle it?[image]

Comment: What is the batch size? 1/2 gallon? If so that's too much sugar for a bakers yeast to deal with.

Comment: 1 full cup for 2 liters? Not sure how much is a cup in grams or oz... A common recipe for a Hard Kvass asking for 100 grams of sugar for 3 liters batch (3/4gallon).

Answer (score 1):

It can take 24-48 hours if the yeast was old. If there is isn't much activity at 48 hours I would aerate and pitch more fresh yeast.

When using dry yeast it's a good idea to proof the yeast as you would in baking first. Even if it's not expired, you never know the storage conditions from the vendor.

When fermentation is done you can transfer to a fresh clean bottle, add 3/4 oz corn sugar (if this is a 1 gallon batch) and cap bottle. Allow 7-14 days to carbonate.

Your recipe doesn't have much yeast nutrients this could be making hard for the yeast, also check the raisins for preservatives their may be a yeast inhibitor on them.

Comment: I just bought the yeast at walmart. It was well before expiration date. I didn't really do anything special beforehand. What would good yeast nutrients be? The stuff inside the bottle is bubbling, but the baloon isn't inflating which is somewhat odd.

Comment: @TalC must be a bad seal or more than a pin hole in the balloon. Nutrients is a blend of dead yeast and minerals. Its available at homebrew stores.

Answer (score 1):

With Kvass you don't want to wait longer then 3-4 days. In fact, all your fermentation should be done in 1-2 days in a warm place, that's why you don't really wanna go above 4%ABV. Then it should be cold-crashed for 1-2 days, filtered and consumed within another 3-4 days... It should not take longer then 7 days from making Kvass to finishing a last pint of it.

So... with that... you should move to a warmer place... I keep my kvasses at 75-80F during fermentation. If that didn't work, re-do it. Also, another method is not to use yeast (like baking yeast), and try do create a starter from either barley (or wheat) of flour (again, rye, wheat or barley). It will make the best Kvass.